# RecyclerView item delete item but not deleting data in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

My problem is that when I click the delete button it deletes the item but not deleting the data in the database.

```
    public class ViewHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView subjectName, day, time , subCounter;
    ImageView delete;

    public ViewHolderClass(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        subjectName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectName);
        day=itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);
        subCounter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subCounter);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    FetchRheinSubject clickedData = fetchDataList.get(pos);
                    fetchDataList.remove(pos);
                    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, fetchDataList.size());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the key of the items to remove, you will first need to query the database to determine those keys:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query applesQuery = ref.child("firebase-test").orderByChild("title").equalTo("Apple");

applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
     }
  });
```